# Alternate row colors without considering invisible rows using pure css

Tags: css

on load my table looks like

```
 <table id="mytable">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //odd color
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //even color
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //odd color
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //even color
 </table>
```

on some action it becomes like

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //odd color
    <tr style="display: none;"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //even color
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> //odd color
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`
 </table>
```

if 2nd row is not visible 3rd row should show even color

Comment: Make a fiddle please.

Comment: @Dilleswari kuncham, what do you really try to do?

Comment: I am guessing you are using `nth-child()` to set the color of your elements. This CSS selector can't take the display property in account to iterate through them. You will have to consider using JS to achive your aim.

Comment: What if all of the second and third and fourth rows are not visible should the fifth be even?, I mean is it like a rule not for just the second?

Comment: @TiyebBellal
Yes, if 2nd, 3rd, 4th rows are not visible 5th should have even color

Comment: @AlexKM: I need to color alternate rows of a table. Each row will have expand and collapse buttons. On expansion one more row will be added, on collapse the added row will be invisible (display property will set to none). After collapse the order of colors is disturbed. I need to fix it using CSS

Comment: @web-tiki: Ya i'm using nth-of-type(even)/ odd.

Comment: @David: Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Dilleswari/fLc1aujb/2/ . You can check on this. Alternate colors should be in proper order. On load first 2 rows are having same color as there exists one more row in between them and it is hidden. I want to avoid this.If you click on the button, all colors are proper

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one:

```js
$("#mytable tr").removeClass("odd even");
$("#mytable tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#mytable tr:visible:even").addClass("even");
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.odd {
  background-color: #99FFFF;
}
.even {
  background-color: #FFFF99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>&nbsp;2222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;3333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;4444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLc1aujb/

Comment: I think we can achieve coloring alternate rows using plain CSS. But i need to achieve it with some conditions like if rows are hidden. I took your sample and modified a little. you can check that here (http://jsfiddle.net/Dilleswari/fLc1aujb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I  think you can't do this only in css. I think some JQuery will help.

```
$('#mytable tr:visible').each(function( index ){
   //Your code to add ODD and even class 
})
```